# What does new (nothrow) operator actually means and why should we use it?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, new-operator

Read this in the working draft of C++.

```
T* p1 = new T; // throws bad_alloc if it fails
T* p2 = new(nothrow) T; // returns 0 if it fails
```

But in what cases the `new` operator throws (or returns `0` in case of `new(nothrow)`).

Comment: When it is out of memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In what cases [does] the new operator throw (or returns 0 in case of new(nothrow))?

When there is insufficient free memory available to allocate the object,
or if the constructor of the new object throws a exception itself
(in this case, even the nothrow-variant of new will throw,
ie. nothrow there is only for memory issues)

Comment: Can there be any other reasons?

Comment: Not that I know of.  Throwing or returning zero means that the creation of the new object failed.  Usually that means there isn't any memory available to create the new object.

Comment: What about throwing constructors?

Comment: @deviantfan what do you mean by throwing constructor? `new` is an operator.

Comment: @Fahad: I mean the constructors of the objects which are created with new.